# getting null `request.parts` posting files to java servlet via jQuery Ajax

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, servlets

here's my js code :

```
function sendMP3ViaAJAX(MP3File) {
    console.log(MP3File.name); //file is present, as I can get its name
      $.ajax({type: "POST",
        url: "saveMP3",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        processData: false,
        data: {'mp3File': MP3File},
        success: function (text)
        {
            response = text;
        },
        complete: function () {
             $("#retourAJAX").html("blah blah");
        }
    });
}
```

but if I debug my Project

```
 @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


        Part part = request.getPart("MP3FILE"); //request.parts is null...
```

[image]

(constant `CHAMP_FICHIER` equals the one defined in AJAX call, i.e. `mp3File` ...) Do you know what's missing ? As I already have dynamically loaded content on the page, I don't want the default HTML POST submit behavior to happen...

Comment: You need to send the file as binary data, not an encoded string. Look in to how you upload using `FormData`

Comment: thank you that did the trick !